# Linux Server RSA key prompts every time in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, key, rsa, fingerprint, hosts

I cloned a disk image to another server to use the same setup with gentoo and nginx. Now every time I connect to the new server from my development api (NetBeans) via sftp, it adds the rsa key to the hosts file. I have to click 'yes' every time I save a file up to the server.

I regenerated the keys because I thought it might be because of the ip change or something, but still the same problem. Is there some ssh configuration I'm missing?

Putty seems to store the keys properly though, as it warned me that the keys had changed and there's only one entry in the cache, but my sftp client doesn't seem to realize that the key is already in the hosts file so it asks and adds it again every time. Driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue in Netbeans, The problem was solved when I pointed the "known hosts" field in the SFTP configuration (remote server settings for the project) to an empty .txt file in my PC. That file can have any name.

Comment: That's the thing, I have the .txt in the known hosts field and it works for any other server I connect to, even the original from which I copied over to the one that isn't working right.

Comment: On linux system, authorize netbeans to write in this file.